# How to loop trought nodeview rows in gtk#

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I have nodeview with 2 columns and need to loop trough values in column a, and value in cell match an condition, i need to ask user what to do, and write user input in column b.

I have tried with

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeview1.Model.IterNChildren(); i++)

    {
        //var x = nodeview1.Columns [0].ToString ();
        //var x = nodeview1.Columns [i].ToString ();
        //var x = nodeview1.Columns [0].Data.Values.ToString ();
    }
```

but can't get any value from cell...

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are iterating on the *view* while to obtain values you should iterate on the *model*. To iterate on model you can use code as follows:

```
Gtk.TreeModel model = nodeview1.Model;
Gtk.TreeIter iter;
if (model.GetIterFirst(out iter)) {
    do {
        Console.WriteLine("COLUMN 1: " +  model.GetValue(iter, 0));
        Console.WriteLine("COLUMN 2: " +  model.GetValue(iter, 1));
    } while (model.IterNext(ref iter));
}
```

The `if` is needed because `GetIterFirst` returns `false` if the model is empty. Then you use it and loop untill `IterNext` returns false.

Also note how you can use `GetValue` on the model to get the value corresponding to the row "pointer" by the `Gtk.TreeIter` and the column (index starts from 0).

Comment: I have been looking for code like this all day. Thanks!